# Client ID for Android application with different flavors

Tags: android, oauth, gradle

I'm creating app that has 15 (!) flavors. The app works with Google Play Services, so I need to register Client ID for application.

Every flavor has own **applicationId** (package name) and Google Developers Console needs **package name** with certificate sha1 fingerprint. All flavors use single keystore.

Should I register 15 different android apps on the Google Developers Console? Is it possible to get single Client ID for different flavors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package name is what identifies an app, so 15 different packages means 15 apks. One project I work on has over 20 and it works fine.